# extract month from date in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of dates in the format 2010-01-31. I can extract the year using

```
#extracting year
year = df["date"].values
year = [my_str.split("-")[0] for my_str in year]
df["year"] = year
```

I'm trying to get the month, but I don't understand how to get it on the second split.

Comment: if you are using pandas you can make them datetime objects using `df.apply` which may be a more useful way to store the data

Answer (score 81):

```
import datetime

a = '2010-01-31'

datee = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d")


datee.month
Out[9]: 1

datee.year
Out[10]: 2010

datee.day
Out[11]: 31
```

Comment: except the question asks for the month

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I would hope the OP wouldn't need so much hand-holding that they would see "then extract the year" and think "but wait, I really wanted to extract the month! I can't use this answer!"

Comment: @SethMMorton, well the answer does not actually show how to extract the year either so unless you have used datetime  before it may not be obvious to a beginner.

Comment: Using the code, I am getting: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Answer (score 25):

Alternate solution

Create a column that will store the month:

```
data['month'] = data['date'].dt.month
```

Create a column that will store the year:

```
data['year'] = data['date'].dt.year
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html

Comment: How do I get one column in 'year-month' format? For example: '2022-07'

Answer (score 7):

if you use `datetime`, you can simply add `.month` at the end of the datetime method

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta, timezone
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 3, 11, 33, 16, 609052)
>>> datetime.now().date()
datetime.date(2022, 1, 3)
>>> datetime.now().date().month
1
```

Comment: I understand it is not directly answering the question, but at the same time, it is also addressing the splitting of date formatting. This might come in handy to someone who is having a similar problem.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> a='2010-01-31'
>>> a.split('-')
['2010', '01', '31']
>>> year,month,date=a.split('-')
>>> year
'2010'
>>> month
'01'
>>> date
'31'
```

Comment: Really? What did you have against `datetime` standard lib?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi perhaps it's too mainstream to him